# Cookies not accessible in middleware.ts

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, amazon-ec2, cookies

I have 2 apps running on aws ec2.

1. front-end ( a next.js 13 server)
2. Back-end ( an express server)

I am setting http-only cookies from the backend like this.

```
response.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
      maxAge: 3.154e10, // 1 year
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
       domain: process.env.CLIENT_SERVER, // Set to your domain
       path: '/' // Accessible to all paths
    });
```

& accessing them in them in the middleware.ts file in the next.js app like this.

```
function parseCookies(cookieHeader: any) {
  const cookies: any = {};
  if (cookieHeader) {
    const items = cookieHeader.split(";");
    items.forEach((item: string) => {
      const [key, value] = item.split("=");
      cookies[key.trim()] = value.trim();
    });
  }
  return cookies;
}

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const cookieHeader = request.headers.get("cookie") || "";
    const cookies = parseCookies(cookieHeader);

    const accessToken = cookies["accessToken"];
    const refreshToken = cookies["refreshToken"];
```

these cookies are accessible when I run my front-end locally & access the api's running on the server running on the ec2.

But when I run both of my apps on ec2, cookies on the front-end are consoled to undefined.

I am not sure what could be causing this.
my front-end on the ec2 is running on a url that looks something like this. https://www.example.com & backend url is https://api.example.com

Comment: The frontend and backend URLs you gave have the same [eTLD+1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/eTLD) `example.com`. Is this also the case for the _real_ URLs? If not, then your cookies are blocked as a [tag:third-party-cookies], they aren't even visible in the DevTools' Application tab.

Comment: Yes, this is also the case for real url's both of the application are running on different sub-domains. so it looks something like this.
front-end url : www.example.com
back-end url : api.example.com